# Must be initialized in constructor base/member?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have this:

```
class SistemPornire
{
Motor& m;
Electromotor& e;
public:
SistemPornire(Motor&,Electromotor&);
}
```

where Motor and Electromotor are two other classes. I try to define the constructor for this class like this:

```
SistemPornire::SistemPornire(Motor& M,Electromotor& E)
{
this->m = M;
this->e = E;
}
```

but it gives me 'SistemPornire::m' : must be initialized in constructor base/member initializer list and 'SistemPornire::e' : must be initialized in constructor base/member initializer list

Comment: There are a million dups of this on SO, it should be closed as [duplicate] so there's one canonical answer, not a million different ones saying the same thing

Comment: Avoid the use of `this->` in C++

Comment: What came up when you searched "constructor base/member initializer list" on Google?

Comment: Some other people on the same course are asking [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SistemPornire+must+be+initialized+in+constructor).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use [**initialization lists**](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html), because references must always be initialized upon creation:

```
SistemPornire::SistemPornire(Motor& M,Electromotor& E) : m(M), e(E) { }
//                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If this wasn't required, the body of the constructor could access those references before they are bound to an object. In C++, however, references must always be bound to an object.

Initializations in an initializion list are always guaranteed to be performed before the body of the constructor is executed (and after the construction of all base class subobjects).

Answer (score 0):

References must be initialized in the member-initializer list:

```
SistemPornire::SistemPornire(Motor& M, Electromotor& E) : m(M), e(E) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SistemPornire::SistemPornire(Motor& M,Electromotor& E)
: m(M)
, e(E)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An initializer list is a set of initializations which are executed before the body of the constructor. In this case, you could use them as such:

```
SistemPornire::SistemPornire(Motor& M,Electromotor& E)
:
    m(M),
    e(E)
{}
```

This will initialize `m` with `M`, and `e` with `E`.

Initializer lists are encouraged for all member initialization, and required for members that *have* to be initialized, such as references. In contrast with for example a pointer, which will have a default junk-value. This is legal, although you would invoke undefined behavior when actually using the pointer.

The reason that references always have to be initialized, is that they are always guaranteed to refer to a valid object (whereas for example pointers are free to point to whatever garbage they want, including a default junk-value). An other consequence of this obligatory initialization is the following code:

```
int someInt;
int& someReference; //Compile-time error: someReference must be intialized
someReference = someInt; //Too little, too late
```

The correct code would of course be:

```
int someInt;
int& someReference = someInt; //OK, someReference has been initialized
```